# Is the obligation of parapet on the owner of resident

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, real-estate, maakeh

According to Halacha, is the mitzvah for Jews to establish a parapet on certain types of roofs an obligation on the resident or owner of the property? Is it the same din as a mezuzah?

Comment: Furthermore, is it the resident of the house (area below the roof) or the resident of the roof (eg. second floor apartment that has a porch over his downstairs neighbor's living room)